# getJSON request returning undefined

Tags: jquery, json, asynchronous

I posted a topic yesterday where a fella made a comment: [How to use $_GET path with file_exists and keep it safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655685/how-to-use-get-path-with-file-exists-and-keep-it-safe#comment17072634_12655685) stating that I'd get "undefined" returned due to JSON being asynchronous. He was right and I've been trying to wrap my head around why, but I feel completely out of my depth. I wonder if someone could explain just what's happening so I can figure out how to use Deferreds to solve this or if there's another solution.

Any help appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Check out this English Language & Usage question about synchronous/asynchronous in layman's terms  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/how-to-best-express-synchronous-asynchronous-in-laymans-terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is

```
function fileExists(path){
    $.getJSON("/ajax/fileExists.php",{ path: path },
    function (data){
        return data.path;
    });
}
```

The problem here is that the inner function is a callback and the `return` inside will be executed after the Ajax request. At this time the outer function `fileExists` has already finished. It only started the request and does not wait for it to end.

To fix this you can make a callback

```
function fileExists(path, callback){
    $.getJSON("/ajax/fileExists.php",{ path: path },
    function (data){
        callback(data.path);
    });
}
```

Use it like this

```
fileExists('/a/path', function(path){ console.log(path) } );
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little out of my depth though. Here the callback() is doing the same as return but waiting first?

Comment: `return data.path;` sends your data back to jQuery. With the callback you can "return" the data as parameter `path` to your own callback function. This way you can access it after the Ajax query has finished.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute your `$.getJSON()` function, execution continues before that function ends because that function is asynchronous.

Consider this code:

```
$.getJSON("/ajax/fileExists.php",{ path: path }, function (data){
    alert("THERE");
});
alert("HEY");
```

This will first alert "HEY", and then "THERE". This happens because once Javascript gets to `$.getJSON()`, it starts executing that request, but does not wait for it to finish executing before continuing with the rest of the code.

So it continues and performs `alert("HEY");`. Then, later, when your `$.getJSON` request completes, your callback function executes and performs `alert("THERE");`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX works asynchronously like you're saying in that: The browser doesn't get "locked up" and wait until it is finished until moving onto the next line (like any of your other normal code would).

Basically by having an AJAX function and simply an `if() else()` afterwards awaiting to test its results, they will always return undefined in that they start instantly. They don't wait until the AJAX is actually completed.

Hence why you need to use callback functions / deferred objects in this case! (Since you are trying to work with the results that come back from the AJAX)